# DefaultAuthenticateScheme doesn't set

Tags: c#, jwt

I set DefaultAuthenticateScheme on startup like this

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme =  JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
});
```

So, I should use something like this :

```
 [Authorize]
 public IEnumerable<UserViewModel> Get()
 {
    return someData;
 }
```

But I had to write this code

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public IEnumerable<UserViewModel> Get()
    {
        return somedata;
    }
```

I google the problem and I notice it should happen when using AddCookie or use AddAuthentication() after AddMVC() in startup, but they are not my case.

Comment: actually I missed something. I did not use  app.UseAuthentication(); in startup.cs. By add this line before app.UseMVC(); the problem goes away.

Answer (score 3):

By default it will use cookie based auth scheme, until you specify explicitly. As Asp .Net Core allows to use combination of `AuthenticationSchemes`. You need to slightly modify your `startup.cs` to remove `AuthenticationSchemes` from Authorize attribute.

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        cfg.SaveToken = true;
        cfg.Audience = "http://localhost:5111/";
        cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            // token config
        };
    });
```

This line of code `cfg.Audience = "http://localhost:5111/";` will set default auth scheme you set up for that particular audience (host).

> However, The `[Authorize]` attribute specifies the authentication scheme or schemes to use regardless of whether a default is configured. For example

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

It will use the specified `AuthenticationSchemes` for that particular controller regardless of default.

Comment: Add set DefaultAuthenticateScheme  but has no effect. I can not use [Authorize], it will not work

Comment: Have you added `AddJwtBearer` as I mentioned you need to specify audience.

Comment: Yes, I did (cfg.Audience = " https ://localhost:44351/";).

Comment: Are you using Identity? And you are saying `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` works fine, right?

Comment: Yes, I use Identity and [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] works fine.

Comment: Can you share the output of console what happens when hit the url, without specifying auth scheme in Authorize attribute.

Comment: Same problem here, have you find the answer, @Sasan?

Comment: yes,  I did not use app.UseAuthentication(); in startup.cs. By add this line before app.UseMVC(); the problem goes away. @ValeriuSeremet

Answer (score 2):

### Order Matters

1. Configure Identity first

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options => {
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApiDbContext>();
```

2. Then configure your authentication

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => {
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; // incase the first one fails
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(jwt => {
    jwt.SaveToken = true;
    jwt.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParams;
});
```

Comment: Oh man, you made my day! Thank you!