# JWT authorization with roles in Identity Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I have trouble with understanding `Roles` in `Identity Core`

My `AccountController` looks like this, I added `Roles` in claims in `GenerateJWTToken` method:

```
[HttpPost("Login")]
    public async Task<object> Login([FromBody] LoginBindingModel model)
    {
        var result = await this.signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, false, false);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var appUser = this.userManager.Users.SingleOrDefault(r => r.UserName == model.UserName);
            return await GenerateJwtToken(model.UserName, appUser);
        }

        throw new ApplicationException("INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT");
    }

    [HttpPost("Register")]
    public async Task<object> Register([FromBody] RegistrationBindingModel model)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser
        {
            UserName = model.UserName,
            Email = model.Email,
            FirstName = model.FirstName,
            LastName = model.LastName
        };
        var result = await this.userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await this.signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);
            return await this.GenerateJwtToken(model.UserName, user);
        }

        throw new ApplicationException("UNKNOWN_ERROR");
    }

    private async Task<object> GenerateJwtToken(string userName, IdentityUser user)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, userName),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, Role.Viewer.ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, Role.Developer.ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, Role.Manager.ToString())
        };

        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.configuration["JwtKey"]));
        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        var expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Convert.ToDouble(this.configuration["JwtExpireDays"]));

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            this.configuration["JwtIssuer"],
            this.configuration["JwtIssuer"],
            claims,
            expires: expires,
            signingCredentials: creds);

        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    }
```

From this code my token works perfectly with `[Authorize]` controller's attribute.

My question is, in which step add `role` to my registered `user` to use (for example) `[Authorize("Admin")]`? How to save `role` to database?

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Authorize] //in this form it works ok, but how to add roles to it with JWT Token?
            //how to register user to role and get this role to JWT Token?
[ApiController]
public class DefaultController : ControllerBase
```

My `ApplicationUser`:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And Enum for `Roles`:

```
public enum Role
{
    Viewer,
    Developer,
    Manager
}
```

How to save information about user role to Identity Database and while login get that role to properly working `[Authorize]` attribute?

**EDIT:**

What i want to do is to store `Roles` like in my enums in User. I want to register user as `Developer`, `Manager` etc. I belive i can do it by `ApplicationUser` and add `Role` property, but from it i couldnt get authorization by attribute `[Authorization(role)]`

Comment: http://bitoftech.net/2015/03/11/asp-net-identity-2-1-roles-based-authorization-authentication-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: @WiktorZychla thansk for your feedback, but my project is `core 2.1`

Comment: Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55701291/defaultauthenticatescheme-doesnt-set/55701900#55701900)

Comment: @MuhammadHannan thanks for your advice, but i think its not a case. I make an edit to my question

Comment: @michasaucer I have the same problem!! did you find any solution for this issue? any hint or document link would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use IdentityUser and identity database in your case, you are using JWT. Create your `User` model with defined `Roles` property and simple persist it in the database. Like:

```
public class User
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public Role Role { get; set; }
}

public enum Role
{
   Viewer,
   Developer,
   Manager
}
```

the token:

```
var user = // ...
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(your_seccret_key);
var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] 
         {
             new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.FirstName),
             new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.LastName),
             new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role)
         }),
     Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
     SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
 };
 var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
 user.Token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
```

controller method:

```
[Authorize(Roles = Role.Developer)]
[HttpGet("GetSomethingForAuthorizedOnly")]
public async Task<object> GetSomething()
{ 
   // .... todo
}
```

Comment: Maybe, but i want to use Identity to store users in roles. I cant find any solution for authorize users in Identity. I need to use JWT if i want to use tokens

Comment: There is no some big benefit of that. Create simple user model, add password to it as well, read password + add salt, than do the encryption, find safe algorithm, don't use md5 or sha1. Never decrypt the password, add try limit and you are prity safe.

Comment: Suppose I don't use Identity, then how do I check for roles? For example - this link says .AddRoles -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-6.0#add-role-services-to-identity - But since I don't use identity then do I still need this line?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built-in Role Management with ASP.NET Identity . Since you are using ASP.NET Core 2.1 , you could firstly refer to below link for enable roles in identity system :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54069826/5751404

After enabling roles , you can register roles/users , then adding roles to user like :

```
private async Task CreateUserRoles()
{   
    IdentityResult roleResult;
    //Adding Admin Role
    var roleCheck = await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Admin");
    if (!roleCheck)
    {

        IdentityRole adminRole = new IdentityRole("Admin");
        //create the roles and seed them to the database
        roleResult = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(adminRole);

        _roleManager.AddClaimAsync(adminRole, new Claim(ClaimTypes.AuthorizationDecision, "edit.post")).Wait();
        _roleManager.AddClaimAsync(adminRole, new Claim(ClaimTypes.AuthorizationDecision, "delete.post")).Wait();

        ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser {
            UserName = "YourEmail", Email = "YourEmail",

        };
        _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "YourPassword").Wait();

        await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
    }

}
```

So that when that user login into your application , you can find `role` claims in ClaimsPrincipal , and that works with `Authorize`attribute with roles.

Comment: In asp mvc yes, but what if i wan to use webapi?

Comment: In web api , directly use JWT token  , or  manually sign-in with role claim :https://stackoverflow.com/a/55645212/5751404

Comment: I still not fully understand your requirement , with JWT token pass to your web api , your web api side need to register user and role in ASP.NET Identity system ?

Comment: I forget to mention that, my bad. My project is `webapi`, i need to have token to login into `webapi` services. Thats why i need something like `JWT`, to external login users from front end (`webapi` proj is my backend)

Comment: @michasaucer , then why not use JWT and use policy based authorization ?  Or you can manually decode token and  sign-in with role claim : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55628357/asp-net-core-2-2-jwt-claims-identity-authentication-for-website/55645212#55645212